# Add Button to TinyMCE Custom Menu

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce, plugin-tinymce

I've added a new button with a menu to the TinyMCE visual editor using this tremendously helpful [tutorial](https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-tinymce-custom-buttons#tmce-section-1) but would now like to add further items to this menu depending on whether various post types are active in my theme. I think I'm on the right track with addMenuItem and 'context' but can't figure out how to set this up in the correct order.

My plugin code:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'nto_add_shortcode_button');

function nto_add_shortcode_button() {
    global $typenow;

    // check user permissions
    if ( !current_user_can('edit_posts') && !current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
        return;
    }

    // verify the post type
    if( ! in_array( $typenow, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) )
        return;

    // check if WYSIWYG is enabled
    if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
        add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "nto_add_tinymce_plugin");
        add_filter('mce_buttons', 'nto_register_my_tc_button');
    }
}

function nto_add_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['nto_shortcode_button1'] = plugins_url( '/text-button.js', __FILE__ );
    return $plugin_array;
}

function nto_register_my_tc_button($buttons) {
    array_push($buttons, "nto_shortcode_button1");
    return $buttons;
}
```

Then, when initiating my post type:

```
function nto_features_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'features',  plugins_url( '/features.js', __FILE__ ), array(), 'false', true );
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'nto_features_scripts', 100 );
```

Then finally, in features.js:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    toolbar: "mybutton",
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.addMenuItem('myitem', {
            text: 'My menu item',
            context: 'nto_shortcode_button1',
            onclick: function() {
                editor.insertContent('Some content');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Returns:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined

Q: How can I correctly initiate this addition to my custom button?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it is an error due to TinyMCE ([`editorremov`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress) I believe) not being loaded yet. Either hook to the `admin_footer` action instead of `admin_head` (interestingly you have declared the `in_footer` option as `true` and it is still not working) or declare the `editorremov` dependency when enqueuing your script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'features',  plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'features.js', array( 'editorremov' ), 'false', true );
```

Comment: Thanks @webtoure but after a little more digging it looks like TinyMCE doesn't play well with wp_enqueue_script so I've reverted to adding in that second function in the same fashion as the first (above) and posted a follow up question specifically regarding editor.addMenuItem.